# Whitelabel Error Page from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

Seems I'm raising a question which has been raised many times, however, before I submitted it I went through most of the answers and found none could resolve my case.

Here's how the issue occurred:
1. Two days ago the index.html file working fine when I typed 'http://localhost:8080/index.html' in browser
2. Yesterday, from the Microsoft Edge when I was trying to debug the JavaScript file for the application, it's noticed the .js file not reflected what I had changed in Eclipse. I was not sure how to bring in my latest changes from Eclipse the .js file to Microsoft Edge, so I deleted both the index.html and the .js file from within Microsoft Edge. Afterwards, I could never again access the http://localhost:8080/index.html, it just ended up with the same error 'Whitelabel Error Page' no matter what I tried.

I believe the issue is not caused by any code changes, can anyone advise if I deleting the 2 files from the Microsoft Edge is anything related to the issue?

--------- With more info ------------
The project structure is by Maven with the index file path below: /social-multiplication-v3/src/main/resources/static/index.html

Here's the pom file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>microservices.book</groupId>
<artifactId>social-multiplication-v3</artifactId>
<version>0.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>social-multiplication-v3</name>
<description>Social Multiplication App (Learn Microservices with Spring Boot)</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Kindly provide which framework you using clearly. Also provide your project structure for debugging the issue.